# I accidently deleted a tag I was following (interested tags) then re-added it. Are there any consequences?

Tags: support, tags, jobs

For example, are there begin and end dates used by the careers module?  So now it looks like I have only been interested in Oracle since July 2011?  The only visual consequence is now it is at the bottom of my interested tags list instead of the top.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has no bearing on careers.

Comment: What has been completed? Did you move the tag so that it is back at the top? Was there a change made to the system so that when tags are removed and re-added, they're automatically placed in their previous position?

Comment: @Cody:  Whoops, thought this got filed as bug (which should have made me think "why is this a bug.  it's not a bug, mark it support. oh it's already support, why are you marking it completed?").  Cheerfully withdrawn.

Comment: `[status-didnt-read-the-tags]`